# Longest increasing subsequence in O(n) time?

Tags: python, algorithm, longest-substring

I'm studying this algorithm for the first time.  CLRS (15-4.6) asks to write an algorithm to run in O(n lg n) time.  The algorithm I came up with seems to run in O(n).  I think I must be misunderstanding something, because even wikipedia says it should take O(n lg n) time.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)
Could somebody tell me why this algorithm (in Python) doesn't work in general or isn't O(n) or doesn't answer the question??

```
"""Attempts to find maximal ordered subsequence in linear time."""

def subseq(n):
    """Assumes the elements of n are unique"""
    if len(n) == 1:
        return n[:]
    first = [n[0]]
    second = []
    for i in range(1,len(n)):
        if n[i] > first[-1]:
            second = first[:]
            first.append(n[i])
        elif not second or n[i] > second[-1]:
            first = second[:]
            first.append(n[i])
    return first

print subseq([0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15])
```

Comment: The particular algorithm you are looking for is in the book, they give it as an example of Divide-and-Conquer on page 68.

Comment: """Assumes the elements of n are unique""" ??? is this a valid assumption??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave some of the debugging to you, but the following does not produce the maximum length substring using your algorithm. I simply added a few numbers to the example you had, so it should have produced `[0, 4, 6, 9, 11, 15]` again, but didn't:

```
>>> print(subseq([0, 12,12,15,14 ,8, 4, 12, 14, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15]))
[0, 12, 13, 15]
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @TJGaffney What about the  "Assumes the elements of n are unique"??

Comment: @FReezeFRancis The example is still illustrative.  I see now the problem comes from a lot front-loaded large elements.  [0, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3] works as a true counter-example.